# Centre text at % with css

Tags: html, css

If I use `text-align: center;` then I can centre text like
[image]

But I want to centre the text at 75% or X% so that I achieve this:

[image]

How can I achieve this with css?

EDIT:

using `left: 75%` or `margin-left: 75%` renders something like this:

[image]

Comment: margin-left, left, padding-left, flex. lots of ways, what does the mark up and css currently look like?

Comment: so this is no more called center

Comment: You can use https://jsbin.com/givutok/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want the text to center w.r.t. to axis at 75%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a mixture of margin and translateX:

```css
.measure {
  width: 75%;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height:10px;
}

span {
  margin-left: 75%;  /* your 75% */
  transform: translateX(-50%);   /* centered */
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="measure"></div>
<span>75%</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the content in a container with a left margin of 50%, then centre it inside that.

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
div { text-align: center; margin: 0 0 0 50%;
border: 1px solid #00c; }
```

```html
<div>Example</div>
```

Comment: Added a border to illustate the box layout.